# Find the property value from JCR using CQ Extjs

Tags: extjs, aem

I have the path to a page in a dialog and i want to read one of the properties from the JCR using Extjs.

Whenever i fire `CQ.HTTP.get('url',function(a,b,c ...`

i either get 403 or html of the page but effectively i want to read the jcr:content property.

PS: I am firing this on Console of the browser and code does is not sitting under any clientlib.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: CQ.HTTP.get(CQ.HTTP.externalize(CQ.utils.WCM.getPagePath() + "/jcr:content.json"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to do it.

```
CQ.HTTP.get(CQ.HTTP.externalize(CQ.utils.WCM.getPagePath() + "/jcr:content.json"))
```